# Android Phonegap + fileOpener - path issues?

Tags: android, pdf, cordova

I'm trying to open a local PDF that is in www/res/PDF in my PhoneGap file structure. I've installed fileOpener, and am calling it like this:

```
$scope.path = "file:///sdcard/Android/data/com.mycompany.myapp_name/www/res/PDF" + $scope.category.pdf;
$scope.openPDF = function () {
        var url = $scope.path;
        console.log("open PDF running with filename " + url)
        window.plugins.fileOpener.open($scope.path);
}
```

When I install my app on an emulator, it doesn't do anything- I guess there is no PDF reader on the emulator. When I install it on a device, it opens the locally installed PDF reader, and then errors

"An error occurred while opening the document!"

I am investigating the probability that I'm directing it to the wrong path, but I can't find much in the plug-in documents about how to divine the correct path name for a local file. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this function for getting the local path, this works for me under android (and lands you straight in your www-directory):

```
    getPath: function() {
    // Get local path for Phonegap
    path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.substr( path, path.length - 10 );
    return 'file://' + path;
},
```